# how to phpunit test $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

I am running Zf2 and in my controller there is line

```
$apiCaller = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

When I run PHPUnit 3.7.27, it throw following error,

```
There was 1 error:

1) MainTest\Controller\myControllerTest::testcreateActionCanBeAccessed
Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR

/home/websites/mysite/module/Main/src/Main/Controller/myController.php:113
```

How can I unit test this line?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836490/best-practices-for-data-providing-phpunit

Comment: Are you using phing or jenkins?

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to access $_SERVER or any other super global in your code. Instead you should use the request object which as all the injection points for unit testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanke to @Mike B,

Change code line to following

```
  $servParam = $this->getRequest()->getServer();
  $apiCaller = $servParam->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
```